# Fibonacci numbers algorithm

Tags: performance, algorithm, numbers, fibonacci

The most common recursive algorithm for Fibonacci sequences looks something like this:

```
unsigned int fib(unsigned int n){
   return (n < 2) ? n : fib(n - 1) + fib(n - 2);
}
```

What is the most efficient fibonacci algorithm in terms of time and space complexity?

Comment: Possible duplicate of this Wikipedia article: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fibonacci_number#Closed-form_expression

Comment: Recursive fibonacci is extremely inefficient. Iterative is much better.

Comment: @jonhopkins I can do constant-time calculation with very little research

Comment: is there an algorithm that is more efficient than O(n)?

Comment: @user2871354 yep. Read the duplicate.

Comment: @JanDvorak I believe that. I have only used recursive and iterative, so I was just commenting based on experience. Reading your linked article now

Comment: @jonhopkins Yep. Iterative is pretty good. But closed-form is much better.

Comment: @JanDvorak maybe the wikipedia link is readable to you, but it's not very much so for me. Gimme code example plz.

Comment: You can do much better than O(n) even without using the "scary floating point" version, with the matrix formula and exponentiation by squaring.

Comment: @harold but isn't that harder to implement than with floats?

Comment: The wikipedia link is hard to understand.....

Comment: @user2871354 if you put it in a loop rather than recursively then using dynamic programming you can do O(n) - although you should really use the closed form formula - or calculate it in advance.

Comment: @user2871354 can you elaborate in the question that you saw the article and why/how you found it hard to understand?

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum agreed. You overshoot int64s pretty fast

Comment: @JanDvorak it a little harder yes, but not too bad. No more than two dozen lines of code. And you don't have to understand floating point magic in order to trust its correctness.

Comment: @harold but you have to understand matrix magic to trust its correctness :-)

Comment: Can someone just put a code example of a more efficient algorithm than O(n) so that I could finally understand....the wikipedia page is very esoteric

Comment: @user2871354 here's a page where they're explained and benchmarked: http://nayuki.eigenstate.org/page/fast-fibonacci-algorithms

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The formula Jan suggested is not very magical (and I can prove it here if you have a basic understanding linear algebra, and are interested).

It's also the fastest way. So resorting to JavaScript (I can do this in other languages you'd like it's simply:

```
var sqrt5= Math.sqrt(5);
var phi = (1 + sqrt5) / 2;

function fibonacci(n){
     return (Math.pow(phi,n) - Math.pow(-phi,-n)) / sqrt5;
}
```

[image]

If for some reason you deeply want to avoid it - you can do `O(n)` (rather than exponential time which you currently have) using a very basic form of dynamic programming. Instead of calculating the last two numbers every time - you remember them.

```
function fib(n){
    var x=1,y=1,t;
    for(var i=1;i<n;i++){ 
        t=x;
        x+=y;
        y=t;
    }
    return x;
}
```

Which returns `fib(50)` almost instantly (the recursive approach takes a huge time here)

Comment: If you can prove that it works with floating point numbers (instead of real numbers), I would be very interested. I've never seen an actual proof of that, just handwaving.

Comment: Wouldn't you have to round to the nearest integer because of imprecision?

Comment: @harold If you can assume `pow` is within 1 ulp of the real value, then the result is within 5 ulp of the real value. This is perfectly fine for values until 2^50 (which is pretty close to the point where you lose the ability to express odd numbers)

Comment: @user2871354 yep. You should do rounding.

Comment: @user2871354 yes, above a certain point you should Math.round the result since JS is incapable of producing accurate outcomes here - but rounding works perfectly for the number range of JS anyway which is bigger than enough for most practical uses.

Comment: @harold I can prove the mathematical formula, and I can show that the error margin is within the tolerable range (by which I mean Math.round) works with JavaScript numbers (which are just plain old IEEE double floating point precision numbers based on their internal presentation (I can show this easily by a truth table comparing the result of the `O(n)` algorithm with the faster closed form - in fact that works for any 'useful' number. If you'd _really_ like me to dig deeper and show convergence (or lack of) for arbitrary numbers held in exponent-mantissa form I can try but I no promises :)

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum well, only if you don't mind.. Experimental verification is nice and all, but I prefer knowing *why* something works, not merely that it does.

Comment: @harold assume at most one ULP of error per math operation. IEEE doubles have 53 bits of precision

Answer (score 1):

Using floating point for computing integers is generally a bad idea. So is in the answers I see above, with the closed formula.

There is a surprisilngly less known formula, which I will try to illustrate below. A better way is to use the following matrix: [[1 1] [1 0]]. It can be shown that raising this to the n-th power will give you [[f(n+1) f(n)] [f(n) f(n-1)]]. You can just use 4 params if you don't want to play with matrices, and, of course, use fast exponentiation to get the result for f(N) in O(log N).

See a more detailed explanation here: [Nth Fibonacci number O(log n)](http://tech-queries.blogspot.hk/2010/09/nth-fibbonacci-number-in-ologn.html)

Let me know if yoou need any extra details.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with the closed form above. It gives the correct numbers, and is well supported by theory. It is also extremely simple and runs in constant time. Given two possible algorithms which produce the same result, I would always pick simple and fast over complex and slow.